# How is a C program divided into pages and then put inside RAM frames according to this scenario?

Tags: c, paging, memory-segmentation

Look at this scheme and then answer the following questions :
[image]

As you see there's a simple C program roughly converted into assembly instructions. For the sake of simplicity let's suppose each instruction is 3 Bytes long and let's suppose page and frame size is also 3 Bytes long.

1. Is it right this flow of procedures ?
2. Is the program really scattered into pages and then put in RAM frames like that ?
3. If so how is the system capable of associating specific pages to the specific segments they belong to ?
4. I read in an OS book that segmentation and paging can coexist. Is this scenario related to this scenario ?

Please answer all this questions and try also to clarify the confusion regarding the coexistence of segmentation and paging. Good reference material about this subject is also very appreciated, specifically some concrete real example with C program and not abstract stuff

Comment: `As you see there's a simple C program roughly converted into assembly instructions.` Is a bit too simplistic. The compiler emits chunks of data for the linker/loader. These chunks can contain code or (initialised) data. Or just the directive: I need xxx amount of automatic (stack) space. The linker will attempt to fulfill these requests, putting it all in place. [segmentation/pagination *could* be part of this, but that comes later]

Answer (score 1):

> Is it right this flow of procedures?
> Is the program really scattered into pages and then put in RAM frames like that?

In principle: Yes.

Please note that the sections ("Code", "Data", "Stack" and "Heap") are only names of ranges in the memory. For the CPU, there is no "border" between "Data" and "Stack".

> If so how is the system capable of associating specific pages ...

I'm simplifying a lot in the next lines:

Reading memory works the following way: The CPU sends some address to the memory (e.g. RAM) and it sends a signal that data shall be read. The memory then sends the data stored at this address back to the CPU.

Until the early 1990s, there were computers that used CPUs and so-called MMUs in two separate chips. This device was put between the CPU and the memory. When the CPU sends an address to the memory, the address (`cpu_address`) is actually sent to the MMU. The MMU now performs an operation that is similar to the following C code operation:

```
int page_table[];
new_address = (page_table[cpu_address / PAGE_SIZE] *
    PAGE_SIZE) + (cpu_address % PAGE_SIZE);
```

... the MMU sends the address `new_address` to the memory.

The MMU is built in a way that the operating system can write to the `page_table`.

Let's say the instruction `LOAD R1,[XXX1]` is stored at the "virtual address" 1234. This means: The CPU thinks that the instruction is stored at address 1234. The CPU has executed the instruction `STORE [XXX2],5` and wants to execute the next instruction. For this reason it must read the next instruction from the memory, so it sends the address 1234 to the memory.

However, the address is not received by the memory but by the MMU. The MMU now calculates: `1234/3 = 411`, `1234%3 = 1`. Now the MMU looks up the page table; let's say that entry #411 is 56. Then it calculates: `56 * 3 + 1 = 169`. It sends the address 169 to the memory so the memory will not return the data stored in address 1234, but the data stored in address 169.

Modern desktop CPUs (but not small microcontrollers) have the CPU and the MMU in one chip.

You may ask: Why is that done?

Let's say a program is compiled in a way that it must be loaded to address 1230 and you have another program that must also be loaded to address 1230. Without MMU it would not be possible to load both programs at the same time.

With an MMU, the operating system may load one program to address 100 and the other one to address 200. The OS will then modify the data in the `page_table` in a way the CPU accesses the currently running program when accessing address 1230.

> ... to the specific segments they belong to?

When compiling the program, the linker decides at which address some item (variable or function) is found. In the simplest case, it simply places the first function to a fixed address (for example always 1230) and appends all other functions and variables.

So if the code of your program is 100 bytes long, the first variable is found at address 1230 + 100 = 1330.

The executable file (created by the linker) contains some information that says that the code must be loaded to address 1230.

When the operating system loads the program, it checks its length. Let's say your program is 120 bytes long. It calculates `120/3=40`, so 40 pages are needed.

The OS searches for 40 pages of RAM which are not used. Then it modifies the `page_table` in a way that address 1230 actually accesses the first free page, 1233 accesses the second free page, 1236 accesses the third free page and so on.

Now the OS loads the program to virtual address 1230-1349 (addresses sent from the CPU to the MMU); because of the MMU, the data will be written to the free pages in RAM.

> I read in an OS book that segmentation and paging can coexist. Is this scenario related to this scenario?

In this case, the word "segmentation" describes a special feature of 16- and 32-bit x86 CPUs. At least I don't know other CPUs supporting that feature. In modern x86 operating systems, this feature is no longer used.

Your example seems not to use segmentation (your drawing may be interpreted differently).

If you run a 16-bit Windows program on an old 32-bit Windows version (recent versions do not support 16-bit programs any more), paging and segmentation are used the same time.

> specifically some concrete real example with C program and not abstract stuff

Unfortunately, a concrete real example would be even more difficult to understand because the page sizes are much larger than 3 bytes (4 kilobytes on x86 CPUs) ...